# using cmake for pascal source files

Tags: cmake, pascal, freepascal

Is there a way to tell CMake to compile .pas source files with standard add_executable and target_link_libraries calls (like for c and c++ projects)?

Currently, we just list the files and use `add_custom_command` / `add_custom_target` and manually set the linker flags, but it would be nice to have something more integrated.

Source file: http://code.google.com/p/hedgewars/source/browse/hedgewars/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Can CMake handle the compiler compiling multiple compilation units in one go?

Comment: You can try to write toolchain for pascal maybe it can helps, see also http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling

Answer (score 0):

According to the CMake docs for [the `enable_language()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_language.html) and this question: [What are the possible values for the LANGUAGE variable in CMAKE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24534384/11107541), it looks like the answer is no, there is currently no such way to build Pascal source code with the standard `add_executable` and `target_link_libraries`.

You can open up [an issue ticket on Kitware's CMake GitLab repo](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues) requesting such functionality be added. If you do so, add a link to it here.