# What are the possible values for the LANGUAGE variable in CMAKE

Tags: cmake

I haven't been able to find a list of possible values for the LANGUAGE variable on the CMAKE.org site or anywhere else.  Would someone please enumerate the values CMAKE recognises?  I specifically need to specify Objective C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Update for CMake 3.16 and later:* CMake [added native support for Objective-C](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.16.html#languages) in version 3.16. The corresponding language strings are `OBJC` and `OBJCXX`. Thanks to squareskittles [for pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534384/what-are-the-possible-values-for-the-language-variable-in-cmake/24536108?noredirect=1#comment103020573_24536108).

*Original answer:* The support for languages varies across platforms.

Currently CMake supports C, CXX and Fortran out of the box on most platforms. There is also support for certain Assemblers on some platforms. For a complete list, check out [the contents of the `Modules/Platform` folder](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Modules/Platform).

The idea is that the language given to the `LANGUAGE` field of the `project` command or the `enable_language` command is just a string, which will then be used by CMake together with [the language dependent variables](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-for-languages) to setup the build system. The Platform scripts shipping with CMake do this configuration for C and C++. In theory, one can add their own language simply by setting the correct variables (although this is quite involved and I do not know of anyone ever successfully doing this).

As for adding support for Objective-C: Since most toolchains use the same compiler for C and Objective-C, you do not need to configure a new language. Simply compile your code as if it was plain C and add the appropriate compiler flags for Objective-C support.

Unfortunately, this is not very comfortable to use and can easily break in corner cases. But until CMake adds explicit support for Objective-C as a first class language, I'm afraid this is as good as it gets.

Comment: As of CMake [3.16](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.16.html), CMake now supports Objective-C or Objective C++ as a language.

Answer (score 12):

Just take a look at all [the `CMakeDetermine<Language>Compiler.cmake` scripts](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Modules) CMake ships with.

This would result - in alphabetic order - in the following you could put in the `enable_language()` call:

1. `ASM`
2. `ASM-ATT`
3. `ASM-MASM`
4. `ASM-NASM`
5. `C`
6. `CSharp`
7. `CUDA`
8. `CXX`
9. `Fortran`
10. `Java`
11. `OBJC` (Objective C)
12. `OBJCXX` (Objective C++)
13. `RC` (Windows Resource Compiler)
14. `Swift`

Evaluated with CMake Version 3.16

**References**

- [`enable_language()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_language.html)
- [Generic rule from makefile to CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293535/generic-rule-from-makefile-to-cmake)

Comment: Looks like **HIP** and **ISPC** have been added getting up to CMake Version 3.21.1