# How to run the Doxygen binary installed by its Conan package inside a CMake script?

Tags: cmake, doxygen, conan

Currently, I programmatically generate a `conanfile.txt` using two functions I have written:

```
message(STATUS "Fetching Doxygen from Conan.")
add_project_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_docs CONAN BUILD_DEPS REQUIRED doxygen/1.9.1)
link_project_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_docs PRIVATE)
```

Together, they create `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps_${PROJECT_NAME}_docs/conanfile.txt`:

```
[requires]


[build_requires]
doxygen/1.9.1

[generators]
cmake_find_package

[options]


[imports]
```

And then they run `conan install .` in that directory and Doxygen is built successfully. As I use `cmake_find_package` generator, a `Finddoxygen.cmake` is created inside that directory as well. So far, so good. However, finding the package like this:

```
find_package(doxygen REQUIRED)
```

Doesn't provide the `DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE` like it's supposed to (it is set to `DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND`). Neither does it provide the `doxygen_add_docs()` for use. So according to [FindDoxygen docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindDoxygen.html) , and as the conan-generated `Finddoxygen.cmake` contains target definition for `doxygen::doxygen` I thought I should use the generator expressions (as per [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_FILE)):

```
add_custom_target(docs
    COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:doxygen::doxygen> ${DOXYGEN_OUT}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
    VERBATIM)
```

But this generates the error: `Target "doxygen::doxygen" is not an executable or library.`
Neither that or `LOCATION` target property work; I used [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34292622/3625094) to view target's properties:

```
doxygen::doxygen IMPORTED = TRUE
doxygen::doxygen IMPORTED_GLOBAL = FALSE
doxygen::doxygen INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS = ;
doxygen::doxygen INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES = ;xapian::xapian;ZLIB::ZLIB;$<$<STREQUAL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:TYPE>,SHARED_LIBRARY>:>;$<$<STREQUAL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:TYPE>,MODULE_LIBRARY>:>;$<$<STREQUAL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:TYPE>,EXECUTABLE>:>
doxygen::doxygen NAME = doxygen::doxygen
doxygen::doxygen TYPE = INTERFACE_LIBRARY
```

And it doesn't provide any property containing the path to the `doxygen` binary that is generated at `~/.conan/data/doxygen/1.9.1/_/_/package/ff3ada3b39a52bebe18da7d8c32a4aead970f75c/bin/doxygen`.

So how can I use it inside my CMake scripts? Am I missing something? Because looking at the example usage in [this resolved issue](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/2537#issue-679540646), it seems that my approach is correct and it should have found the binary and set `DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE`.

Comment: I think you can try to access it like: `CONAN_BIN_DIRS_DOXYGEN/doxygen` ?

Comment: I agree with @ymochurad, this is working for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `CONAN_BIN_DIRS_DOXYGEN/doxygen`.

Also list of other useful variables: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake.html

Comment: From what I understand, this explains how to access the executable from a CMake script conditionally to the fact we are sure that conan was used to install doxygen. How does this answer fit the case where we don't know if Doxygen was installed systen-wide, using conan, or brew?