# Generic rule from makefile to CMake

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am trying to "translate" the flowing vanilla makefile lines into CMake syntax.

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.foo)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.foo=.bar)

my_rule: $(OBJS)

%.bar: %.foo
    make_bar_from_foo  $@  $<
```

#### Working ugly attempt

```
FILE(GLOB SRCS "*.foo")
SET(outFiles)
FOREACH(SRC ${SRCS})
    SET(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME "${SRC}.bar")

    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
      OUTPUT "${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}"
      COMMAND make_bar_from_foo ${SRC} ${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}
      DEPENDS "${SRC}")

    SET(outFiles ${outFiles} "${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}")
ENDFOREACH(SRC)
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(my_rule ALL DEPENDS ${outFiles})
```

I understand that it's going to generate one command per file instead of something generic. Any simplest/cleanest way to do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In CMake you can always declare your own compiler language. So in your case you can e.g. do:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(MakeBarFromFoo NONE)

set(
   CMAKE_FOO_COMPILE_OBJECT 
       "make_bar_from_foo <SOURCE> <OBJECT>"
)

file(GLOB SRCS "*.foo")
add_library(my_rule OBJECT ${SRCS})
set_source_files_properties(${SRCS} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE FOO)
```

Then you can simply work with it as you would with other [object library](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library) targets. But you will only get things like the `.bar` extension if you `enable_language(FOO)` (and that requires more work, see below).

Examples delivered with CMake itself are `ASM` or `RC` compilers.

---

### The `enable_language(FOO)` Version

This needs four more files you could put in e.g. your project's `CMake` folder:

**CMake\CMakeDetermineFOOCompiler.cmake**

```perl
# Find the compiler
find_program(
    CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER 
        NAMES "make_bar_from_foo" 
        HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
        DOC "FOO compiler" 
)
mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER)

set(CMAKE_FOO_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS foo;FOO)
set(CMAKE_FOO_OUTPUT_EXTENSION .bar)
set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER_ENV_VAR "FOO")

# Configure variables set in this file for fast reload later on
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/CMakeFOOCompiler.cmake.in
               ${CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_DIR}/CMakeFOOCompiler.cmake)
```

**CMake\CMakeFOOCompiler.cmake.in**

```perl
set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER "@CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER@")
set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER_LOADED 1)
set(CMAKE_FOO_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS @CMAKE_FOO_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS@)
set(CMAKE_FOO_OUTPUT_EXTENSION @CMAKE_FOO_OUTPUT_EXTENSION@)
set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER_ENV_VAR "@CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER_ENV_VAR@")
```

**CMake\CMakeFOOInformation.cmake**

```perl
# This file sets the basic flags for the FOO compiler
if(NOT CMAKE_FOO_COMPILE_OBJECT)
    set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER> <SOURCE> <OBJECT>")
endif()
set(CMAKE_FOO_INFORMATION_LOADED 1)
```

**CMake\CMakeTestFOOCompiler.cmake**

```perl
# For now just do nothing in here
set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER_WORKS 1 CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

---

Then your `CMakeLists.txt` file just looks like this:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(MakeBarFromFoo NONE)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake")
enable_language(FOO)

file(GLOB SRCS "*.foo")
add_library(my_rule OBJECT ${SRCS})
```

Comment: Wow. That's going the extra mile.

Comment: I regret I have only one upvote for you!

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is correct, and it hardly can be significantly improved.

This is just how CMake works: each of its "rules" is concrete; you cannot create a "template rule". The reason for that is *platform independence*: not every build systems supports "templates" for rules.

On the other side, CMake supports creation of the "rules" within functions/macros. So typing repeated parts can be easily reduced.

Comment: GNU Make, at least, supports the creation of rules within functions.macros, [e.g.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html)

Comment: @MikeKinghan: Yes, you are right. Actually, I used that some time ago. I have fixed the answer.