# include_directories doesn't work when adding a new language in CMake

Tags: cmake, compiler-construction, g++, clang, cmake-language

I am trying to add a new C-like language which called "foo" in CMake, which needs to use a specific modifed complier

I tried from [Generic rule from makefile to CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293535/generic-rule-from-makefile-to-cmake) and it seems work when compiling a single `foo` file.

However I found that command `include_directories` doesn't work when I use it.

Here I list the changes which I made

**CMakeDetermineFOOCompiler.cmake:**

```
find_program(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER NAMES "clang++" PATHS "~/out/install/bin" DOC "FOO Compiler")

mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER)
message(STATUS CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER:  ${CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_FOO_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS foo)
set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER_ENV_VAR "FOO")
configure_file(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeFOOCompiler.cmake.in
               ${CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_DIR}/CMakeFOOCompiler.cmake @ONLY)
```

**CMakeFOOInformation.cmake:**

```
include(CMakeCommonLanguageInclude)

if(UNIX)
  set(CMAKE_FOO_OUTPUT_EXTENSION .o)
else()
  set(CMAKE_FOO_OUTPUT_EXTENSION .obj)
endif()

set(_INCLUDED_FILE 0)

if(NOT CMAKE_FOO_COMPILE_OBJECT)
    set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER> <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> -o <OBJECT> -c <SOURCE>")
endif()

if(NOT CMAKE_FOO_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY)
  set(CMAKE_FOO_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY
      "<CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER> <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_FOO_FLAGS> <LANGUAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CREATE_FOO_FLAGS> <SONAME_FLAG><TARGET_SONAME> -o <TARGET> <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
endif()

if(NOT CMAKE_FOO_CREATE_SHARED_MODULE)
  set(CMAKE_FOO_CREATE_SHARED_MODULE ${CMAKE_FOO_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY})
endif()

if(NOT CMAKE_FOO_LINK_EXECUTABLE)
  set(CMAKE_FOO_LINK_EXECUTABLE
    "<CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_FOO_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
endif()

set(CMAKE_FOO_INFORMATION_LOADED 1)
```

**CMakeFOOCompiler.cmake.in:**

```
set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER "@CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER@")
set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER_LOADED 1)
set(CMAKE_FOO_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS @CMAKE_FOO_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS@)
set(CMAKE_FOO_OUTPUT_EXTENSION @CMAKE_FOO_OUTPUT_EXTENSION@)
set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER_ENV_VAR "@CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER_ENV_VAR@")
```

**CMakeTestFOOCompiler.cmake:**

```
set(CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER_WORKS 1 CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

**My CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(FOO_demo)

enable_language(FOO)

set(FOO_home /home/FOO_20210731/operations)

include_directories(${FOO_home}/include)
add_executable(test_foo test.foo)
```

When I use command `make`, I got a warning:

```
/home/FOO_20210731/operations/include: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

and then it comes a fatal error, shows that included head files not found：

```
/home/FOO_20210731/operations/include/FOO_header/foo_rt.h:3:10: fatal error: 'FOO_header/foo_rt.h' file not found
#include "FOO_header/foo_rt.h"
```

It seems that `include_directories` didn't work, and I guess that some changes need to be added on those `.cmake` files.
How to make `include_directories` working for my case?

Comment: "it comes a fatal error, shows that included head files not found." - Please, show (add to the question post) the exact error message. Also you could examine the exact command line generating by CMake. You could see that command line if invode `make` with additional `V=1` parameter.

Comment: `and then it comes a fatal error` What fatal error? Please show all the errors and all the commands verbatim from the compilation. Please use `make VERBOSE=1` or `cmake --build <path/to/build/dir --verbose` and show the full output. Anyway, try to `set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_FLAG_FOO "-I")` or similar or  I think `include(CMakeGenericSystem.cmake)`.

Comment: Thanks guys for answering, and Sorry that I forgot to list the information of the fatal error(now I post it onto question). Actutally when I use command ```set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_FLAG_FOO "-I")```, the  ```include_directories``` works well again. May I ask why do I need this extra command?