# Is there any way I can generate a Gradle for Android Studio with CMake?

Tags: android-studio, cmake, cmake-gui

With CMake Gui I can use my CMakeList.txt to generate a solution for visual studio. What about Android Studio? Is there any way I can generate a Gradle ( I believe that is what is called? ) for Android Studio with CMake?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? CMake is a cross-platform build configuration tool, specialized on native languages [like C, C++ or Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534384/what-are-the-possible-values-for-the-language-variable-in-cmake). If you just want to build for one platform - in this case Android - there is no reason to generate the build configuration in an extra step. Additionally, a Gradle project doesn't need to be configured for each platform individually, because it runs on java, which is cross-platform itself.

Another issue that I see: Gradles powerful dependency management would be hard to describe with cmake.

If you are interested in directly building native Code for Android, without Gradle involved, this might be interesting for you: https://github.com/forexample/android-cmake